# Slide between divs (not images like in Bootstrap Carousel)

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, frontend

Hello I wants to have on my page something like carousel but for content of div not with image.
(I mean that there would be links, text and many other things, not only image)
But all I found already is bootstrap carousel that works when I wants images.
I know that I can create css that define if and div is shown, and not, and then call ajax function that change classes of these elements to make other div shown, and other hidden.
But I have no idea how to make a animation of elements being slided.

I spend many hours on looking for already created thing like that. But I don't know how to call it and only thing I found was this bootstrap carousel for images.

I would rather use someone's else solutions because I'm pretty afraid that I wouldn't do it as good as others already did. But I hadn't found other's solution.

Do I have to do it myself, or is there one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/ for that. I have used it myself and it is perfectly capable of making a carousel with div's that don't necessarily contain images.

I'm sure there are other libraries out there that achieve the same goal, so owl-carouses definitely isn't your only possibility.